# Hair not emerging from all vertices in vertex group

Tags: particles, hair, vertex-groups

I am new to blender (version 2.83.5), and I am trying to render a lattice of spheres of alternating colours. My plan was to do so by subdividing a rectangle into several smaller faces, defining two vertex groups corresponding to alternating vertices on the rectabgle, then adding hair particles which render as the sphere objects.

This seems to partially work but, strangely, not all vertices in the vertex group are generating spheres. I have the "Random Order" button unchecked, and the number of particles exceeds the total number of vertices in the mesh. The missing spheres are all concentrated in one region of the rectangle (see the attached image) and particles are missing from both vertex groups.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Will

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue - I had placed a solidify modifier on the rectangle and it was conflicting with the hair somehow. Removing the modifier has fixed it.